# Why isn't my for loop using the updated global variable?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop, google-maps-api-3

I am writing a script that places markers on a map. To decode the zip code into latitude and longitude I use the Geocoder function. This function updates the global variable. But I can't get the loop to use the updated variable. I've struggled for a while, but can't figure out why the for loop is not using the updated variable. Can someone take a look? Thx in advance.

```
AndereKlant1 = {
    title: '<strong>Naam</strong><br>\
            Dienst',
    lat: 51.986847,
    long: 5.955350,
    adres: "1011AC",
    geocodeLat: "",
    geocodeLong: "",
};

/*
    AndereKlant2 = { 
        title: '<strong>Naam</strong><br>\
                    Dienst',
        lat: 51.986846,
        long: 5.955350,
        adres: "",
        geocodeLat: "" ,
        geocodeLong: "" ,
      };

*/
locations = [
    [AndereKlant1.title, AndereKlant1.geocodeLat, AndereKlant1.geocodeLong, 0],
    //     [AndereKlant2.title, AndereKlant2.lat, AndereKlant2.long, 0],  
];

function initMap() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


    var iconAanvraag = {
        url: 'link to icon',
    };

    var iconDienstverlener = {
        url: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/32/map-marker-icon.png',
    };

    var iconBestaandeklanten = {
        url: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/origami-colored-pencil/32/yellow-home-icon.png',
    };

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': AndereKlant1.adres
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            // no need to define it in outer function now
            AndereKlant1.geocodeLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            AndereKlant1.geocodeLong = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            /*
                    alert(AndereKlant1.geocodeLat);
                    alert(AndereKlant1.geocodeLong);
            */

        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: false,
        rotateControl: true,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        gestureHandling: 'cooperative'

    });
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        map: map,
        polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: "#036396",
            strokeOpacity: 0.6,
            strokeWeight: 6,
        },
        suppressMarkers: true,
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        //    alert(locations[0][1]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: iconBestaandeklanten,
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the Geocoding service with `geocoder.geocode(...)` is asynchronous. This means that the request to the service is made in the background and it takes some time to finish. The callback function (`function(results, status) {...}`) that you pass to the `geocode` method gets executed when the Geocoding service responds with the result of the request.

In the meantime, while the request is being processed in the background, your code continues to run and the for-loop gets executed before the Geocoding service has responded with the updated coordinates.

So if you want to update the position of your markers with data from the Geocoding request, you should put your for loop inside the callback function that you pass to `geocoder.geocode` method.

Example:

```
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': AndereKlant1.adres
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      locations[0][1] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      locations[0][2] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map,
          icon: iconBestaandeklanten,
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      }

    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
```

Also, keep in mind that changing the values `AndereKlant1.geocodeLat` and `AndereKlant1.geocodeLong` does not update the values in the `locations` array. The `locations` array has copies of the values from `AndereKlant1`.

Reference: [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?&_ga=2.230960607.1305096795.1525114021-620990840.1522850954&__utma=236542612.620990840.1522850954.1525291261.1525291261.1&__utmb=236542612.0.10.1525291261&__utmc=236542612&__utmx=-&__utmz=236542612.1525291261.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=171706211#GeocodingRequests)

Comment: Thx for your answer! Really helpful!